# Magento 2 product count issue in the layered navigation in category listing page

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation, listing

I am using Magento 2.2.6, i have a color attribute of multiselect type. i had assigned this attribute to all product type. when i assign one group product of color red to category "Category 1" then in the layered navigation i can see many color options like below

Color

Red (2)
Blue (1)
Green (1)
Yellow (1)

i debugged why this is coming. i found that this group product has 4 simple product of color red,blue,green & yellow.

so thats why when i added one group product i am able to see this much color option in the layered navigation

What i require is i dont want to include this simple product's color options in the layered navigation.

Any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please check with below step possible to issue solved.

Case 1) Go to Backend set Out of stock display No (Make sure some product out of stock)
Go to any category , check count of layer navigation of attribute

Case 2) Go to Backend set Out of stock display Yes
Go to any category , check count of layer navigation of attribute, it will show same

It does not count out of stock product count into layer nav.

Check below file

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.0/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider.php#L117